# Javascript not working as expected for the function if record exist also

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a `js` code which returns me a `datatable` count when I add the `doc no`

But even if the record exist it still goes into the else part

Here is the code:-

```
 function getOtherDBInward() {
        StrPriFnName = "FunGetOTHERDBInward(" + document.getElementById('TxtInwardNo').value + ")";
        var ObjPriXMLHTTP = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        ObjPriXMLHTTP.open("GET", "FrmInwardXMLHTTP.aspx?para=" + StrPriFnName, false);
        ObjPriXMLHTTP.send("");

        if ((ObjPriXMLHTTP.responseText) != "") {
            var StrPriData = ObjPriXMLHTTP.responseText.split('~');
            document.getElementById('checkDBMkey').value = StrPriData[0];
            document.getElementById('checkDBMDocNo').value = StrPriData[1];
        }
        else {
            alert("ERROR: Document does not exist");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Also see the function

```
public static string FunGetOTHERDBInward(object[] args)
{
    string StrPriRetVal = "";
    DataAccessLayer ObjPriDal = new DataAccessLayer(Providers.ConfigDefined);
    DataTable Dt1 = new DataTable();
    Dt1 = ObjPriDal.ExecuteDataTable("Select mkey, doc_no from erp190516.dbo.inward_doc_tracking_hdr where doc_no='" + args[0].ToString().Trim() + "'");
    if (Dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        StrPriRetVal += Dt1.Rows[0]["mkey"].ToString().Trim() + "~" + Dt1.Rows[0]["doc_no"].ToString().Trim();
    }
    return StrPriRetVal;
}
```

**NOTE**

> I get as unspecified error at line

```
var ObjPriXMLHTTP = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
```

Comment: You may looking for synchronous operation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200856/synchronous-request-with-ajax-in-a-loop

Comment: @JaydipJ: thanks for the link, how can I make it _reuse_ according to my requirment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace

```
var ObjPriXMLHTTP = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
```

With

```
var ObjPriXMLHTTP ;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
  ObjPriXMLHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest;
else
  ObjPriXMLHTTP = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

Since `if (window.XMLHttpRequest)` detects whether the browser has XMLHttpRequest functionality if so the XMLHttpRequest object is constructed that way. i.e code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari

Otherwise the code blindly assumes it can create the XMLHttpRequest by calling ActiveXObject functions i.e code for IE

for more detail <kbd>[Create an XMLHttpRequest Object](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp)</kbd>

Comment: hi, I tried your code but it is not working. IT still going in the else part.